# What are the properties of $item passed in the auto_update_{$type} filter?

Tags: updates

I'm trying to auto update a theme only when it's a minor update. I know I can use the [`auto_update_{$type}`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/aaf99e691391cfceb004d848450dbbf3344b1bee/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-automatic-updater.php#L183) filter where `$type = theme`. The only examples of using that filter I've seen have been using the callback `__return_true` and not utilizing the second parameter `$item`.

```
add_filter( 'auto_update_theme', '__return_true' );
```

My problem is that I don't want to auto upgrade on major version changes. I was hoping the second parameter passed to the filter would contain some information on the versions, but I can find nothing in the source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is one element of the `response` Array that's a property of the object stored in the `update_plugins` or `update_themes` site transient.

That transient looks like this (`var_dump()`ed):

```
object(stdClass)#1 (4) {
  ["last_checked"]=>
  int(1519305016)
  ["response"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["akismet/akismet.php"]=>
    object(stdClass)#2 (11) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(21) "w.org/plugins/akismet"
      ["slug"]=>
      string(7) "akismet"
      ["plugin"]=>
      string(19) "akismet/akismet.php"
      ["new_version"]=>
      string(5) "4.0.3"
      ["url"]=>
      string(38) "https://wordpress.org/plugins/akismet/"
      ["package"]=>
      string(56) "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/akismet.4.0.3.zip"
      ["icons"]=>
      array(3) {
        ["1x"]=>
        string(59) "https://ps.w.org/akismet/assets/icon-128x128.png?rev=969272"
        ["2x"]=>
        string(59) "https://ps.w.org/akismet/assets/icon-256x256.png?rev=969272"
        ["default"]=>
        string(59) "https://ps.w.org/akismet/assets/icon-256x256.png?rev=969272"
      }
      ["banners"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["1x"]=>
        string(61) "https://ps.w.org/akismet/assets/banner-772x250.jpg?rev=479904"
        ["default"]=>
        string(61) "https://ps.w.org/akismet/assets/banner-772x250.jpg?rev=479904"
      }
      ["banners_rtl"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["tested"]=>
      string(5) "4.9.4"
      ["compatibility"]=>
      object(stdClass)#3 (0) {
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So the `$item` for a plugin update will look like the `akismet/akismet.php` element in the `response` Array, meaning you can access the version with `$item->new_version`.

It is however important to note that there's zero guarantee that plugins and themes all use the same version numbering system. For example, in a WordPress version `X.Y.Z`, `Y` is a major version and `Z` is a minor version (and `X` is just for show, apparently), but in WooCommerce `X` is a major version and `Y` is a minor version. Every plugin and theme could be different.